# Why am I getting #REF as a result to my output?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Fairly new to working with R and I keep getting #REF to my output. I was not receiving it before and it all started after I went back into my spreadsheets to delete some data and reimported. Any help or advice is welcome.

I know this may not be an issue right now, but when I go to visualize the data using ggplot2, I get a REF bar along with my other ones. I hope to get rid of it or learn why its there.

```
### Difference between the days bikers members and casuals like to ride?

bike_rides %>% 
  group_by(day_week_label, member_casual) %>% 
  drop_na() %>% 
  summarise(n = n()) %>% 
  mutate(percent = round(n / sum(n), 3)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(percent))
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I assume it's an artifact of a reference error in Excel prior to importing the data into R.

Comment: Thanks, @Phil I'll definitely look into my excel files to see what the problem could be.